# Fourier transform and filter given data set

Tags: python, filter, fft

Overall, I want to calculate a fourier transform of a given data set and filter out some of the frequencies with the biggest absolute values. So:

**1)** Given a data array D with accompanying times t, **2)** find the k biggest fourier coefficients and **3)** remove those coefficients from the data, in order to filter out certain signals from the original data.

Something goes wrong in the end when plotting the filtered data set over the given times. I'm not exactly sure, where the error is. The final 'filtered data' plot doesn't look even slightly smoothened and somehow changes its position compared with the original data. Is my code completely bad?

**Part 1):**

```
n = 1000
limit_low = 0
limit_high = 0.48
D = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, n) + np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, n) * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, n))) + np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, n))**2 + np.sin(np.linspace(1, 6*np.pi, n))**2

scaling = (limit_high - limit_low) / (max(D) - min(D))
D = D * scaling
D = D + (limit_low - min(D))                       # given data

t = linspace(0,D.size-1,D.size)                    # times
```

**Part 2):**

```
from numpy import linspace                                    
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft, ifft

D_f = fft.fft(D)         # fft of D-dataset

#---extract the k biggest coefficients out of D_f ---

k = 15
I, bigvals = [], []                                        
for i in np.argsort(-D_f):                
    if D_f[i] not in bigvals:            
        bigvals.append(D_f[i])          
        I.append(i)
        if len(I) == k:
            break

bigcofs = np.zeros(len(D_f))             
bigcofs[I] = D_f[I]                      # array with only zeros in in except for the k maximal coefficients
```

**Part 3):**

```
D_filter = fft.ifft(bigcofs)
D_new = D - D_filter

p1=plt.plot(t,D,'r')
p2=plt.plot(t,D_new,'b');
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('original data', 'filtered data'))
```

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues I noticed:

1. you likely want the components with largest absolute value, so `np.argsort(-np.abs(D_f))` instead of `np.argsort(-D_f)`.
2. More subtly: `bigcofs = np.zeros(len(D_f))` is of type `float64` and was discarding the imaginary part at the line `bigcofs[I] = D_f[I]`.  You can fix this with `bigcofs = np.zeros(len(D_f), dtype=complex)`

I've improved your code slightly below to get desired results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft, ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
limit_low = 0
limit_high = 0.48
N_THRESH = 10

D = 0.5*np.random.normal(0, 0.5, n) + 0.5*np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, n) * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, n))) + np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, n))**2 + np.sin(np.linspace(1, 6*np.pi, n))**2

scaling = (limit_high - limit_low) / (max(D) - min(D))
D = D * scaling
D = D + (limit_low - min(D))                       # given data
t = np.linspace(0,D.size-1,D.size)                    # times

# transformed data
D_fft = fft.fft(D)

# Create boolean mask for N largest indices
idx_sorted = np.argsort(-np.abs(D_fft))
idx = idx_sorted[0:N_THRESH]
mask = np.zeros(D_fft.shape).astype(bool)
mask[idx] = True

# Split fft above, below N_THRESH points:
D_below = D_fft.copy()
D_below[mask] = 0
D_above = D_fft.copy() 
D_above[~mask] = 0

#inverse separated functions
D_above = fft.ifft(D_above)
D_below = fft.ifft(D_below)

# plot
plt.ion()
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)
l1, = ax1.plot(t, D, c="r", label="original")
l2, = ax2.plot(t, D_above, c="g", label="top {} coeff. signal".format(N_THRESH))
l3, = ax3.plot(t, D_below, c="b", label="remaining signal")
f.legend(handles=[l1,l2,l3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: With the mask you "cut off" the data with absolute value greater than the k maximal values of the transformed data respectively hold onto the data values with lower absolute value, whereas my code above picked out (maybe rather clumsily) the max. values. I think I get your steps and find them much more elegant than my attempt, yet I'm not completely sure what I did wrong. Even if I correct the error you found, it seems that my code does not return the seemingly correct graph of yours.

Comment: @JtSpKg it looks like there were two issues. 1) you probably want max absolute components as I mentioned (`for i in np.argsort(-np.abs(D_f))`), and 2) bigcofs did not capture the imaginary part because it was type `float64`.  You can fix that with `bigcofs = np.zeros(len(D_f), dtype=complex)`